Is the following matrix positive semidefinite?
Suppose that $A = (a_{ij})$ be a $3\times 3$ real symmetric positive semidefinite matrix with entries in $(0, \infty)$. Then can we say that the matrix defined by $B = (b_{ij}),$ where $b_{ij} = \max\{1,a_{ij}\}$ also (real, symmetric) positive semidefinite?
My try: If we have that all diagonal entries are greater than 1 and all other entries to be less than 1 then we indeed have the result since, in that case, $B$ can be written as the sum of the diagonal matrix $\operatorname{Diag}(a_{11}-1, a_{22}-1, a_{33}-1)$ and the matrix with all ones.
Any help is appreciated!
Edit: The motivation of this problem comes from a result of Schur- the cone positive semidefinite matrices is invariant under the Schur/ Hadamard product. In other words, the monomials $x^k$, when applied entrywise on positive semidefinite matrices preserves the positivity. So, I was checking the combinations of this monomials in the above sense which may preserve positivity!

Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1/2& 5/3\\ 1/2 &2&1/2\\ 5/3&1/2&3\end{pmatrix}$$ Then $$B=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1& 5/3\\ 1&2&1\\ 5/3&1&3\end{pmatrix}$$ The matrix $A$ is positive definite. According to wolframapha the smallest eigenvalue is  $\approx 0,037.$ The matrix $B$ is not positive semidefinite. Its smallest eigenvalue is  $\approx -0,034.$

That's a nice example! Can you give some insight for this approach? I am asking since I have a follow-up question when $b_{ij}$ is taken to be $\max{a_{ij}, a_{ij}^{2}}$?

I have put numbers greater than $1$ on the main diagonal. Then numbers less than $1$ on upper and lower diagonals. Next I tried to find the values at the corners as large as possible, keeping the positive semidefinitness. I hoped that replacing the upper and lower diagonals with $1$ would spoil the positive semidefinitness. Perhaps it is possible to provide a simpler example so that calculations can be performed by hand.

Thanks for the prompt response. I was trying the same technique with the problem mentioned in the comment about positive semidefiniteness of the matrix with entries $b_{ij}= \max{a_{ij}, a_{ij}^{2}}$ but couldn't get anywhere. I am not asking for the answer but do you have any hunch for this?

I have no idea how to test the new problem on examples. I would start with diagonal slightly larger than $1$ then small coefficients on the upper and lower diagonal and the largest possible coefficients at the corners, larger than $1.$ What is the origin of your problem ? You may include that in your post.
